# Arrays in TList

Tags: arrays, delphi, tlist

I Tlist into the Array of string not much of a problem here, but I'm throwing Array I want to list all the value is going to last.

It's The last value is listed every time. 
I want Like that

Value1q

Value2q

Value3q

bla bla. So TList in the Array I want to list all the elements.

And sorry my bad english

```
public  var
  { Public declarations }
  Address : Array Of String;
  AddressList: Tlist;


//Form Create
 AddressList := Tlist.Create;
 SetLength(Address, 3);



//Copy Listview Button
var
  i : integer;
  AItem: TlistItem;
begin
  AddressList.Clear;

  for i := 0 to SelectedListView.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    AItem := SelectedListView.Items.Item[i];
    Address[0] := AItem.SubItems[0];
    Address[1] := AItem.Caption;
    Address[2] := AItem.SubItems[1];
    AddressList.Add(Address);
  end;

//Always being counted towards the last value
for i := 0 to AddressList.Count -1 do
    MultiUser.Text := TArrayStr(AddressList[i])[1]);
```

Comment: What is your question? I can see the obvious problem with your code that you don't manage memory correctly. You cannot store managed objects in a `TList`. That you really need is `TList<TArray<string>>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks answer. It's The last value is listed every time. I want Like that 
{Value1q}
{Value2q}
{Value3q} bla bla.

So TList in the Array I want to list all the elements.

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you use?

Comment: Yes, Delphi version is extremely important here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem that I see here is that a dynamic array is a managed type, and that relies on reference counting. The reference counting only works so long as the array is referenced by correctly typed variables. When you store to untyped `Pointer`, as you do with `TList`, the compiler cannot count the references properly.

On top of that basic design flaw, you only actually have one array in your program. You just add the same pointer to the `TList` object every time you call `Add`. Remember that dynamic arrays are reference types, without any copy-on-write. So they behave like true references.

If you have a modern Delphi then you solve this with a generic container that is typesafe. For instance `TList<TArray<string>>` where `TList<T>` is from `Generics.Collections`.

For legacy versions of Delphi you cannot expect to store a dynamic array in a `TList`. That just will not fly at all. You can hack the reference counting yourself, but you need to clear hand and a good understanding. The next coder that comes across your code will despise you.

So, for legacy versions of Delphi I suggest that you replace `TList` with `TObjectList`. Set `OwnsObjects` to `True`. And replace the dynamic array of `string` with a `TStringList`.

An alternative solution for legacy Delphi would be to use a multi-dimensional array: `array of array of string`.